# how to get a enum from a integer in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Enum Value from index in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692664/how-to-get-enum-value-from-index-in-java)

i have a enum like:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

how i have a integer like 1=ONE 2=TWO 3=THREE

now i get a integer like 2 and want to generate the EnumTest from it and it should return TWO
**how to do this?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692664/how-to-get-enum-value-from-index-in-java

Comment: `EnumTest.values()[Number-1]`

Comment: You should never use Integers for getting `Enum`.

Comment: @AmitD Never is a bit strong - he might be tied to a library where he need to send the number 1 but he wants to encapsulate it in an enum for example.

Comment: @assylias Yes. I agree. I missed this perspective.

Comment: @AmitD. Sometimes, you are left with no other choice. If you are in control of both ends you always avoid having to do so, is closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to associate the `int` with a `enum` value.

You can do

```
static final EnumTest[] VALUE = { null, ONE, TWO, THREE };

return VALUE[num];
```

or

```
return EnumTest.values()[num-1];
```

or use a Map.

Answer (score 6):

Or, for more flexibility:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

    private int value;


    EnumTest(int value) {
       this.value = value;
    }

    static EnumTest getByValue(int i) {
      for (EnumTest e : values()) {
          if (e.value == i) {
              return e;
          }
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Think about future developpers which see this enum, if you leave an undocumented `values()` use, anybody can break it by adding new items. Because no documentation enforce the order of the elements.

Comment: But the `getByValue` method will be `O(n)`, right? Can't you just do a `O(1)` array lookup?

Comment: @eboix, indeed, in this form its not as performant as an array lookup, but if you really need performance then maybe you don't use enums but int (in this case), or you cache the result in a static array, which will be here similar to the `values()`array but can contain more logic. Always the same equilibre to find between optimisation and maintanability/readability/flexibility

Comment: @eboix For O(1), you can use a `Map<Integer, EnumTest>` that you pre-fill in a static block. Then the body of `getByValue(int i)` is simply `return map.get(i);`.

Comment: @eboix Also this form is less error prone suppose `FOUR` is skipped and `FIVE` is there then `EnumTest[]` will throw ArrayIndexOutofBound if 5 is passed assuming he has `5= FIVE`

Comment: Why would you skip `FOUR`???? Maybe for space considerations.... Maybe to save a few extra bytes.... And if you skipped `FOUR` by accident, then **it is good that you should get an error message....**

Comment: @eboix, you not, but think about future maintainers adding a new feature 2 years later

Comment: Why the heck would you care about O for a one off, this trival?

Comment: U could use valueOf as the name of the method rather than getByValue

Answer (score 0):

Get it like this `EnumTest.values()[Number-1]`, where Number is your number (i.e. 1, 2, 3).

(Subtract 1 from the number because, for example, `ONE` will be at index 0, and `EnumTest.values()[1]` will give you `TWO`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the ordinal, here is some useful information:

- you can get the ordinal of an enum constant with e.g. EnumTest.ONE.ordinal()
- you can retrieve all enum constants with EnumTest.values()

From that, you can do what you want.

If you want to add a property with some arbitrary value, you can create a property + constructor + getter in your enum:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    THREE(3), ONE(1), TWO(2);
    private int val;
    EnumTest(int val) { this.val = val; }
    int getVal() { return val; }
}
```

This is more stable (values stay if you rename / insert / move them).

But are you sure you really need to get an int value? You should always work with the enum constants when possible e.g. EnumTest.THREE instead of 3.

I'd suggest to google for the various tutorials on java enums.

Answer (score 0):

Try `EnumTest.ordinal()` for getting int values. 
  It will start from 0.
For getting enum from value, you can use `EnumTest.values()[i]`.

Thanks.