# Create custom enums and , output the corresponding enums, along with the year of that date object

Tags: java

I created custom enums for the days of the week and months of the year like this:

```
public enum Days {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

```
public enum Months {
    JANUARY,
    FEBRUARY,
    MARCH,
    APRIL,
    MAY,
    JUNE,
    JULY,
    AUGUST,
    SEPTEMBER,
    OCTOBER,
    NOVEMBER,
    DECEMBER
}
```

If I have a date object how to output the corresponding enums, along with the year of that date object?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your [enums accessible by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692664/how-to-get-enum-value-from-index-in-java), and then using Date's getMonth() and getDay() to access them through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LocalDate in Java 8.

Code Snippet:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(now.getDayOfWeek());
System.out.println(now.getMonth());
```

Console:

```
2022-02-17
THURSDAY
FEBRUARY
```